# Swipe between tabs ics style using mono for android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm looking for an example how to swipe between tabs using mono for android. Unfortunately I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I would really appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.. ?

This is what I'm trying to do,

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html (Swiping Between Tabs)

Comment: I think the Java Android equivalent question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354115/swipe-to-switch-tabs-on-android-like-the-youtube-google-music-apps - hopefully the answers there will be helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems to be a bit difficult to implement this using mono for android at the moment. http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Using-the-New-Compatibility-Packages-and-TabActivity-Deprication-td4705492.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the latest version of Mono for Android, you will get the behavior for free if you use Android 4.0+ and the ActionBar in tab navigation mode.

If you need a general guide on how to use the actionbar, I suggest this blogpost: http://fizzylogic.azurewebsites.net/2012/03/05/mono-for-android-by-example-the-action-bar/